# How to add an image gallery to a custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, custom-post-type

I'm making a website in Wordpress for a cat shelter for my final assessment (I'm a student) and I'm stumbling upon an obstacle..

I have made a custom post type where the shelter can upload their cats. In this custom post type they can add all kinds of things like age and color (thanks to Advanced Custom Fields plugin). It works very well and I'm happy with the results since I'm new to custom post types.

I want to add a gallery to the custom post types so the shelter can show more than one picture. It should work like the product images in Woocommerce.

I know the pro version of ACF has the image gallery option, but since it's a school project, I can't pay the fee.

I have looked online for answers for my question, but none of them seem to work, are outdated or require the acf pro version. Does anyone have a solution? Maybe some lines of php I can add to my custom post type plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check Meta box , works similar way but it have some extra features for free ,there is also online tool so you can generate code for meta box from there https://metabox.io/online-generator/. for free version its doesn't have acf like generator you have to depend on its online generator.